# Android How to create pagination with number

Tags: android, kotlin, pagination, retrofit

I'm quite new with android and code with kotlin. I'm queering data from api call using `Retrofit` and I'm trying to populate that data into `RecyclerView` list. I'm familiar with basic Api call and populating data to Recyclerview Adapter.

But now I'm trying to make pagination and I came across Paging library. I tried to look around on how to create pagination and come across with multiple of good tutorial for that.

- https://medium.com/@harunwangereka/android-paging-library-with-kotlin-coroutines-b96602e3fae3
- https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-paging-library-tutorial/

Most all `PagedListAdapter` example I saw is endless scrolling. I'm trying to create a pagination with numbers like this instead:

[image]

I want to limit the page with only around 20 data and the number of page will depends on the total number of data fetched from the api.

My api get call is as this, where I can set data per page and query the data based on page number

```kotlin
@GET("/api/data/history")
fun getDataHistory(
    @Query("cardNo") cardNo: String?,
    @Query("perPage") perPage: Int?,       //data per page
    @Query("pageNumber") pageNumber: Int?  //page number
): Call<DataHistory>
```

Response data:

```
{ 
  "metaData" : { 
    "totalCount": 150,  // ( maximum 200 ) 
    "perPage": 10,      // ( default 20 ) 
    "pageNumber": 3     // ( default 1 )  
  },
  "data" : [
    {
      "statementDate": null,
      "transactionDate": "2020-02-20 10:22:32",
      "postingDate": "2020-02-20",
      "cardNo": "70838153000829349",
      "stan": "0",
      "qty": 10.000,
      "totalAmount": 24.00
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Is it still relevant for me to use Paging library? How should I tackle this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-paging-library-tutorial/ tutorial is clear , what is your question exactly?

Comment: hi @miladsalimi, I was wondering instead of making it endless scrolling, how can I incorporate the pagination button instead. Something like what we usually do to paginate list of table. Instead of append the `loadAfter` fetched data to the recyclerview, it refresh the recyclerview with the 2'nd page, 3'rd and so on. 

I've made something similar the normal way without Paging library by  dynamically create buttons and fetch data based on onclick button. I was wondering if the same effect can be done with paging library and at which part of the code should I made the changes.

Comment: Hi, i am stuck on the same issue... did you find a solution to this...???

Comment: Hi @shivamchawla, I scrap the idea on using the Paging library. Instead I just create a simple class to dynamically create button and changing fetch data based on button click.